# Java, MultiThreading, and Raspberry Pi

Tags: java, multithreading, raspberry-pi2

So I have my multi threading partially working. When I run my program the very first time after compiling it only runs 1 or 2 of the 3 threads. Then running it again right after, it runs perfectly fine with all of the threads activated and running. I can't think of any reason why all of the threads would not run on the first execution of the java class, and then start working on the second execution of the class after the first one has been terminated.

I am using Pi4j on a Raspberry Pi 2. I need the code to run fine the first time because I am trying to run this on bootup of the Pi.

This is where I start the threading.

```
public class Doors {
public static void main(String[] args) {        
    Thread door1 = new Thread(new DoorSwitch(0));
    door1.start();
    Thread door2 = new Thread(new DoorSwitch(1));
    door2.start();
    Thread door3 = new Thread(new DoorSwitch(2));
    door3.start();
}
```

This is what the Thread is running. The threading is passing in the value of what I call the door.

```
public class DoorSwitch implements Runnable{    
int p;
int doorID;
int tempPin;
static DBConnection db = new DBConnection();//create a new object of database connection class
public DoorSwitch(int currPin){
p = currPin;
    doorID = (p + 1);
}
public void run()
{
    try{
        final GpioController gpio = GpioFactory.getInstance();
        final GpioPinDigitalInput[] gpPins = {
                 gpio.provisionDigitalInputPin(RaspiPin.GPIO_28, PinPullResistance.PULL_UP),
                 gpio.provisionDigitalInputPin(RaspiPin.GPIO_29, PinPullResistance.PULL_UP),
                 gpio.provisionDigitalInputPin(RaspiPin.GPIO_27, PinPullResistance.PULL_UP),
         };
        for (int i=1; i<gpPins.length; i++){
            if(p == i){
                tempPin = p;
            }
        }
        final GpioPinDigitalInput door = gpPins[tempPin];
        door.addListener(new GpioPinListenerDigital() {
            @Override
            public void handleGpioPinDigitalStateChangeEvent(GpioPinDigitalStateChangeEvent event) {
                if(event.getState() == PinState.HIGH){
                    try{
                        db.dbConnection();
                        System.out.println(doorID);
                        System.out.println("Door Open! " + p);
                        String update = "UPDATE `door` SET `status`=" + 1 + " WHERE `id`="+ doorID +";";
                        db.getStatement().executeUpdate(update);
                        String log = "INSERT INTO `door_log` (`door_id`, `status`) VALUES ("+ doorID + ",1);";
                        db.getStatement().executeUpdate(log);
                    } catch (SQLException | ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                if(event.getState() == PinState.LOW){
                    try{
                        db.dbConnection();
                        System.out.println(doorID);
                        System.out.println("                Door Closed! " + p);
                        String update = "UPDATE `door` SET `status`=" + 0 + " WHERE `id`="+ doorID +";";
                        db.getStatement().executeUpdate(update);
                        String log = "INSERT INTO `door_log` (`door_id`, `status`) VALUES ("+ doorID + ",0);";
                        db.getStatement().executeUpdate(log);
                    } catch (SQLException | ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                //System.out.println(" --> GPIO PIN STATE CHANGE: " + event.getPin() + " = " + event.getState());
            } 
        });
        while(true) {
            Thread.sleep(500);
        }

        // stop all GPIO activity/threads by shutting down the GPIO controller
        // (this method will forcefully shutdown all GPIO monitoring threads and scheduled tasks)
        // gpio.shutdown();   <--- implement this method call if you wish to terminate the Pi4J GPIO controller
    }catch(Exception e){

    }

}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. 
Thanks

Comment: You say, "...it only runs 1 or 2 of the 3 threads."  How do you know?  What is this code supposed to do?  What is it actually doing instead?  What have you tried doing so far to pinpoint the problem?

Comment: Your threads don't do anything but register an event handler, and then `while(true) sleep(500);`  Why would you use a thread for that?

Comment: You're using a `for` loop to test whether `p` is in the range [0..2].  You don't need to use a loop for that.

Comment: I'm using the multi threading to run 3 different magnetic door sensors, this way i don't have to run 3 separate classes for each sensor. This way I have 1 main class and run it 3 times calling a different gpio port each time it is ran. I know when it does and doesn't work by activating the sensor and then checking the database to see if a log was recorded. But when i run it for the first time after rebooting all of the threads do not get activated.

Comment: Your threads don't appear to do anything except call `door.addListener(...)`, and then sleep forever.  Why not just have the main thread add the listeners?  What good is a thread that sleeps forever?

Comment: I think I understand what you're saying, so if I remove the sleep function, would that be able to solve my problem?

Comment: In that case, your threads will register the listeners and then immediately die.  That's better, but I still don't see why you need the threads in the first place.... Unless there's some reason you know of that I don't know of why the main() thread is not _allowed_ to call `GpioFactory.getInstance().provisionDigitalInputPin(...).addListener(...)`.

Comment: So is just having 3 seperate classes for each door switch better than having 1 main class and then calling it 3 times with the threads? The reason I ran it in threads because 1. I wanted to expand my learning with threads, and 2. because I thought it would be more efficient to run it with threads. They are there because I want the door sensors to constantly be running in the background on the Pi, monitoring to see if a door opens or closes and then logging it into the database for the systems records. But not all of the GPIOs are being set up in the first execution.

Comment: I think you'll need to learn more about the Raspberry Pi library classes.  When you do `...addListener(GpioPinListenerDigital() {...})` call, you're creating a new instance of an anonymous subclass of `GpioPinListenerDigital`, and then you're registering the new instance to be called by the library when the level on an input pin changes.   That call is going to happen in some _event handler thread_, which probably is created by the library, but I don't know for sure because I _don't_ know Raspberry Pi.  The identity of the thread that creates and registers the handler probably does not matter.

Comment: Add  sleep if 2 seconds before registering listeners. Put a try-catch around the register and other code. I dont think u need threads, so debug the rest if code and log exceptions

Answer (score 1):

check db: shared, not protected when used, and created in each thread.

The result can be unpredictable.

I propose:

1 Add this

```
 static final Object db_sync=new Object();
```

2 Initialize db only once, and call it in the constructor of DoorSwitch

```
static DBConnection db=null;

static db_initialize()
{

synchronized(db_sync)
 {
 if (db==null) 
    db = new DBConnection();//create a new object of database connection class
  }

}
```

3 Surround the use of db

```
synchronized(db_sync)
 {
  // Do what you want with db
  }
```

Comment: I'm confused on what you are asking?

Comment: he is asking to fix the static shared object that is not synchronized